# Alfresco: Add a tag based on the location of the document

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've been struggling with a little script that should be easy to implement:
I've added a rule on a folder that runs a script.
The script should get the folderlocation of the uploaded or incoming document and add the location as a tag:

```
var url = document.properties.locale.nodeRef;
document.addTag(url);
```

It should be something like this, but this doesn't work.
how should I do it?

Comment: and what's the actual problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. Does the script API support the folderlocation of a file, if yes, what syntax should I use?

Comment: Does a `document.commit()` at the end help? Also, fairly sure that the noderef isn't what you want as a tag...

Comment: addTag does not need a save() - What's your "locale" property? Do you mean sys:locale or do you want to set the path of the document as tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be as follow.First try with my code then just replace logic to add path.

```
if (!document.hasAspect("cm:taggable"))
document.addAspect("cm:taggable"); 
 document.addTag("test");
```

You can replace "test" with accessed path of your document.

Answer (score -1):

As @gagravarr says you should save changes. But I think the correct statement is

document.save();

Comment: addTag() does not need a save() - only property changes need a save()

Comment: Thank you for your comment @alfrescian. Indeed I'm not 100% sure that document.save() is needed, but in the example in [test_taggingService.js](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/test-resources/org/alfresco/repo/tagging/script/test_taggingService.js) it's used.